# How to create responsive ImageView?

Tags: android, responsive

I'm building a game for my final school project, and I have this followed problem :

When I try to place ImageView on the screen they are placed in different place depending on the mobile screen size. (Example below)

https://i.ibb.co/WcgvNkq/screen.png (don't have the reputation to post image)

So my question is how can I do to have ImageView responsive for all devices.

I already try to delete manual width for match_constraint but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is very vague. Maybe this is helpful https://proandroiddev.com/getting-your-constraints-right-constraintlayout-786254ed1166

Comment: I want responsive for "new device" I want to have the same placement as my screen

Comment: What I understood from your query is, you want to fit the image to the Image View irrespective of screen size.

If this is the query, then see the Image View attribute android:scaleType="centerCrop

Or scaleType

Comment: You can use ConstraintLayout to achieve the right behaviour. You have to choose at which border "anchor" each ImageView and then create a "link" between them in the appropriate way. Something similar to this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4N4bCdyGcUc/maxresdefault.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the ConstraintLayout to achieve your query, here is the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Answer (score 0):

you should use ConstraintLayout or RelativeLayout to align your ImageView on the screen.
You could use [article](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1) for example

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use Android's Constraint Layout. Constraint layout basically allows you to place your views based on the constraints.
It is a lot to explain in one shot on a answer.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/9475-constraintlayout-tutorial-for-android-complex-layouts
This one explains the concept with neat images and their concepts. Check it out.
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout
This is an official documentation. It also has enough contents to get you started.